# How do I get a list of needed packages

Tags: package-management, compiling

I want to know how to get a list of needed packages for a program.

I want to get one program/application from one computer to another, by taking every package that is needed and compile it on the other computer.

How do I get a list of needed packages for a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)

Search for the needed package.

That will list the package.

[image]

Here in the Example, click on the `trusty`

It will bring you to the following page

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vlc

Here, the packages marked with red dots are the dependent packages for the main package. You need to install them also.